# Left aligning markers in legend with legend title using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, legend

I'm trying to make a plot with Matplotlib, and I would look to have the legend on the top left. Without a legend title this is working fine with the code below, but when I add a legend title which is longer than the legend labels, the markers shift.

Is there any way I can prevent this and have them all align to the left?

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
x = np.arange(0, 4 * np.pi ,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))

# Working fine without legend title
axs[0].plot(x, y, label='sin')
axs[0].legend(title='', loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0,1), facecolor='white', edgecolor='white', framealpha=1)

# Position shifts when using long legend title
axs[1].plot(x, y, label='sin')
axs[1].legend(title='Some longer title', loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0,1), facecolor='white', edgecolor='white', framealpha=1)

plt.show()
```

[image: plotlegendtitle]

Comment: does anything happen if you change the ```bbox_to_anchor``` value in ```axis[1].lenged()``` ?

Comment: Yes then the position of the whole legend box shifts but the relative position of markers to the legend title stays the same.

Comment: Oh god now I understand what you say. It might be because there's 2 plots next to the other, and not due to the legend? Did you try to show only the 2nd plot on its own?

Comment: Yes that's actually what I started with, I just show 2 charts here for easy comparison, but I get exactly the same with one chart only.

Comment: Understand, then I don't know what to say more. Maybe someone more experienced than us can solve the problem. Put more tags to be more visible. If not, ```gnuplot``` or ```Matlab``` is the way to go, I'm sure you might know about them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround in a still unresolved [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12388). Apparently the default alignment is "center", which can be changed like this.

```py
axs[1].get_legend()._legend_box.align = "left"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, your code does something similar to what you want to have by me simply changing the `bbox_to_anchor` argument from the `axs[1].legend()` command.

Now it reads: `bbox_to_anchor=(-0.1,1)` and it produces the below. Of course, you can change the first value to `-0.15` or so if you want it to be more to the left.

[image: output]

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data
x = np.arange(0, 4 * np.pi ,0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 4))

# Working fine without legend title
axs[0].plot(x, y, label='sin')
axs[0].legend(title='', loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(0,1), facecolor='white', edgecolor='white', framealpha=1)

# Position shifts when using long legend title
axs[1].plot(x, y, label='sin')
axs[1].legend(title='Some longer title', loc='lower left', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.1,1), facecolor='white', edgecolor='white', framealpha=1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed put the legend marker in the right place, but I was rather looking for a way to control the relative position of the legend title to the legend labels to make them all align.

Comment: Legend returns a legend object which has a get_title method which will give you access to the title text object, which you should be able to put wherever you want.